# socket.io, server emit event before client set up listener for that event

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io

In the following code snippet(using node.js and socket.io library), **sometimes** (and sometimes not) server emit event `something` before client side set up socket listener for `something` event which will cause that associated anonymous function will not execute.

**Client-side: index.html**

```
<script src="socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
<script>
   ...
   var socket = io.connect('http://localhost:8080/abc');
   ...
</script>
<script src="/somewhere/test.js"></script>
```

**Content of test.js**

```
...
console.log(new Date().getTime(), 'debugging');

socket.on('something', function(data) {
// will not execute
console.log(data);
});
...
```

**Server-side:**

```
io.of('/abc').on('connection', function(socket) { 
   console.log(new Date().getTime(), 'EMIT SOMETHING');
   io.of('/abc').emit('something', 'b');
});
```

Result of console.log on the client side: `1439057954676 debugging`
Result of console.log on the server side: `1439057954114 EMIT SOMETHING`

Why server emit event before client set up listeners in the above example?

Comment: FYI, you should be aware that you may be exposed to different timing issues when running on localHost vs. running to a remote server over the internet because localHost responses can be soooo much faster.

Comment: @jfriend00, of course, but described scenario shouldn't happen ever, regardless environment where code is running

Comment: Yes, logic would say that should not happen, but can you point me to a spec that says that should never happen when running on localHost?  With images, if you do `img.src = "xxx.jpg";` followed by `img.onload = function() {...}`, you CAN miss the `load` event (if the image is in the cache) so it is not beyond the browser to trigger something before you get a handler attached.

Answer (score 0):

Try putting both **var socket = io.connect('http://localhost:8080/abc');** and **socket.on('something', function(data)** in the same **script** tag.
(Essentially try making your whole script in one HTML element, instead of separating them.)

Comment: This should not make any difference.

Comment: If these script blocks are not inline but in separate .js files (likely) then it absolutely could make a difference.

Comment: Well, I don't know how browsers process HTML, but in my mind, the only possible way a server might be able to send a message to the client before it is even able to execute a simple line of code, is as follows:  
the client loads the first ".js" file and then executes it (forming a connection). and then it starts loading the other ".js" file which takes some time, by this time the server already emits the event.
putting all your client code in the same ".js" file should fix this.

Comment: Except that is not what the OP's code shows.  It shows two inline `<script>` tags which are obviously in the same file.

Comment: Two things:
1. Maybe the example code is different from the actual code the OP has on his cumputer.
2. Maybe even an inline script start executing before letting others load? (seems highly unlikely, but is there any other explanation?)

Comment: @jfriend00, My mistake, indeed, logic that will set up socket listeners is in another file. See edited question.

Comment: Once again, it seems like putting **var socket=...** inside test.js will solve the problem. Let me know if it worked.